# I am using same action for 5 buttons and want to know which button is called?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ibaction

I am using  same action for 5 buttons and want to know which button is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
button.tag=1;
[view addSubview:button];

-(void)aMethod:(id)sender{

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

int clickedBtnTag = button.tag ;

Nslog("clicked button tag is %d",clickedBtnTag);

}
```

Try this and then please revert me..

Answer (score 4):

In such a case please try assigning unique tags to the buttons.

In the target method regain the button tag as follows

Eg

```
-(void)targetMethod:(id)sender{

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

int clickedButtonTag = button.tag ;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give tag value to your button in nib then add this in your button action:

```
allbtn = sender;
    btntag = allbtn.tag;
    NSLog(@"btntag:%d",btntag);
    if(btntag==1)
    {
    }
```

Simple now you easily find what button you tap.

Comment: allbtn is UIButton *allbtn;

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
button.tag=1;
[view addSubview:button];
```

then use:

```
-(void)aMethod:(id)sender{

UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

int clickedBtnTag = button.tag ;

Nslog("clicked button tag is %d",clickedBtnTag);

}
```

Try this and then please revert me..